# Async.each :only one callback after all executed

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async.js

I have an `async.each`function to  the following things in an order.

1.Get image size from array.

2.Crop the image.

3.Upload to AWS s3.

Now i want to show single success message after all upload.

```
async.each(crop_sizes,function (result,cb) {
    //crop image
    gm(path)
            .resize(result.width, result.height,'^')
            .crop(result.width, result.height)
            .stream(function (err,buffer) {
                //upload to s3
             s3.upload(params,function(err,success){
                   if(!errr){
                     conseole.log(uploaded);
                    }
                })
            });

  });
```

It output like

```
uploaded
uploaded
uploaded
uploaded
```

But i want to show success message after all upload is it possible with `async`

Comment: there is typos in your code. What is `errr` i don't see it defined anywhere. uploaded is a string or var ?

Answer (score 2):

Async.each takes a 3rd augment which is:

```
A callback which is called when all iteratee functions have finished, 
or an error occurs. Invoked with (err).
```

You will want to setup that third argument to know when all the uploads have completed or if some have failed.

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

Answer (score 2):

(1) When you work `async.js` in general, you should always trigger the callback i.e. `cb` when your task completes or even when there is an error. It should also be once and no more for each task. If you don't trigger it or trigger it more than once within the same task, your code might hang or you will get an error, respectively.

(2) [async.each](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) has 3 arguments: `coll`, `iteratee`, `callback`. You only use 2. The last argument `callback` is triggered when all tasks are completed.

```
async.each(crop_sizes, function task(result, cb) {
    //crop image
    gm(path)
        .resize(result.width, result.height, '^')
        .crop(result.width, result.height)
        .stream(function (err, buffer) {
            if (err)
                return cb(err); // we use 'return' to stop execution of remaining code
            //upload to s3
            s3.upload(params, function(err,success){
                if (err)
                    return cb(err);
                cb(null, success);
            });

            // you could also simply do s3.upload(params, cb);
        });
}, function allTasksAreDone (err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    // do something now
});
```

(3) I think if you want to get the result of each task, you're better off using [async.map](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map). here is an [example](http://code.runnable.com/UyR-6c2DZZ4SmfSh/async-map-example-for-node-js). The only difference is that your `callback` will have an additional argument given which is an array of all your `success`es.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should try to wait for each "each" return and then console.log if you think everything is fine. Inside your async.each , except with a complicated code you wont be able to know that every "each" worked well